# Difference between hexbinary and hex decimal

Tags: certificate

What is the difference between hex binary and hex decimal

How a certificate in hex binary format will look like?

Please let me know

I have one element in xsd (xml schema) file as

```
  <element name="ABC" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="hexBinary"/>
```

I need to prepare xml for the above xsd element, but what is hexBinary?
How can I fill that element with hexbinary content?

Here in [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_misc.asp) also, you can see that datatype, but nothing mentioned about that datatype.

Answer (score 2):

`hexBinary` is binary data encoded in hexadecimal.

Valid input :

```
0FB8
```

Invalid would be any odd number of characters (cause they need to be binary data).

More detail on this page : http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_hexBinary.html

Comment: Wait that rubbish, actually the defintion is obscure : http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-xml-schema-comments/2004AprJun/0082.html . Do you have to create an example by hand?